# CentOS 6.4 Intel 82574L, 1000/100/10Mbps,8x LAN Intel 82580EB 1000Mbps，4xSFP

Tags: centos6, nic, intel

I could not get 
*Intel 82574L*, 1000/100/10Mbps,8x LAN
*Intel 82580EB* 1000Mbps，4xSFP
up and running with CentOS 6.4

Tried to install `kmod-e1000e.3.3.4-2.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm` for *Intel 82574L*
and `kmod-igb-5.2.15-1.el6.repo.x86_64.rpm` for *Intel 82580EB*

Also made another try using source package of Intel and compiling but no success

Any Clue can help

Comment: Did you verify that these drivers are installed correctly in your system? You can try for example `modinfo igb`, `modinfo e1000`. Also, you can verify that they are loaded using `lsmod | grep module_name`

Answer (score 2):

Solved: download `kmod_igb` and `kmod_e1000e` from [repo](https://elrepo.org/tiki/Download)

and append this setting to grub file

```
pcie_aspm=off e1000e.IntMode=1,1 e1000e.InterruptThrottleRate=10000,10000 acpi=off
```